# PowerBI Desktop and PowerBI Service Displaying Variables Differently

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to display a simple table and a slicer. One variable is a true/false variable and displays as "TRUE" or "FALSE" in PowerBI desktop, but when uploaded to PowerBI Service displays as "0" and "-1" on both table and slicer. How do I get it to show true/false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that right now your column is a text data type.  If you switch the data type in the get-data/power query section to true/false than it should display correctly in the service.

If that doesn't work than you can just create a conditional column in your data that resolves to the text strings "TRUE" or "FALSE" and that should work as well.

Comment: Thanks. It was true/false in the source dataset but Power Query auto"corrected" it to a mixed type field.